# getElementsByClassName - не работает

Tags: javascript

Наверно на этом форуме это уже классика, но я не могу ничего сделать. Объясните, пожалуйста. Я новичок.

Мой код: `document.getElementsByClassName('ol-title ol-upper ol-light pr-20');`

Ошибка: `Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementsByClassName is not a function`

Comment: Извините наверно за глупый вопрос. Я видео ответы и вопрос остальных и там про какие-то `for`, `var`. Я ничего не понимаю

Comment: А где это вообще запускается?

Comment: В консоли, собираюсь делать расширение в Tampermonkey и посмотрел туториал на ютубе. Там изначально делали так. Вот я и решил проверить тоже

Comment: А точно нигде не перепутали латинские буквы с русскими? В браузере не может быть такой ошибки... Хотя, если на том сайте, где это пробуете, кто-то додумался написать `document.getElementsByClassName = null` — будет такая ошибка) Пробуйте `document.querySelectorAll('.ol-title.ol-upper.ol-light.pr-20');` ?

Comment: О, вы мой спаситель. Спасибо большое. Тут есть то, что я искал. Спасибо